# How to combine 2 endpoints express.js into a new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 2 existing endpoints `/balance /transactions`
What is the best way to create a new one `/balance-and-transactions` and not rewrite existing code
For instance:

```
a('/balance', () => {
 foo()
 res.send({ /*some json with balance */ });
});

b('/transactions',() => {
 boo();
 res.send({ /*some json with transactions */ });
});


newendpoint('/balance-and-transactions', () => {
 foo();
 boo();
 res.send({ /*some combined json with balance and transactions altogether */ });
});
```

Is it a good idea to call 2 requests inside newendpoint (internal call)?

```
 newendpoint('/balance-and-transactions', () => {
     data1 = request('/balance');
     data2 = request('/transactions');
    // then combine data1 and data2
     res.send({ /*some combined json with balance and transactions altogether */ });
    });
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at using [`next()`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router). But, how precisely to combine the result of two endpoints depends on your current implementation, so please include it in the question.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to combine these endpoints, but if you still want to do this, it’s better to use a dash instead of underscore `/balance-and-names`